# Modifying existent code to get search results from API

Tags: python, json, api

I'm currently working on a small hobby project and encountered some problems that I find myself unable to solve. First of all I'd like to point out that my programming experience is limited to some computational physics and therefore quite far away from my current problem.

To put it simply, I'd like to do some data analysis with data requested from an API. The API I have in mind is [this](https://github.com/AniList/ApiV2-GraphQL-Docs) one (documentation is linked right there (can't post any more links)). There is also a quite nice addition to deal with this provided [here](https://github.com/ccubed/PyMoe). I was able to write a basic program to get the data for a given `id` and do some simple calculations. Since it is quite unhandy to have to look up the `id` of every title the author of [3](https://github.com/ccubed/PyMoe) has provided a search option. So I'm able to search for an entry by `name`, `season` and some other `key` defined in [here](https://github.com/ccubed/PyMoe/blob/master/Pymoe/Anilist/search.py).

This is certainly handy but I fail to see how I can effectively use this in a maybe a little bit more complicated context. Lets for example say I do the following, as suggested in the `Read me` file of [3](https://github.com/ccubed/PyMoe).

```
from Pymoe import Anilist
instance = Anilist()
instance.search.anime("King")
```

This will quite obviously search for the word "King" in the title, but if I'd like to search for the entries with the highest popularity, which is also a key in the definition of `search` (as can be seen in [4](https://github.com/ccubed/PyMoe/blob/master/Pymoe/Anilist/search.py) line 87), how would I go about doing that?

Another issue I'm facing right now, which is partially related to the above, is the goal to modify `search`. I've done that for the `get` (added another key and it works just fine), but I'm struggling with this for `search`. Let's say I want to add the key `seasonYear` (which can be found [here](https://anilist.github.io/ApiV2-GraphQL-Docs/page.doc.html) in line 19). My attempt was to change lines 69-94 in [3](https://github.com/ccubed/PyMoe) to

```
    query ($query: String, $page: Int, $perpage: Int) {
        Page (page: $page, perPage: $perpage) {
            pageInfo {
                total
                currentPage
                lastPage
                hasNextPage
            }
            media (search: $query, type: ANIME) {
                id
                title {
                    romaji
                    english
                }
                coverImage {
                    large
                }
                averageScore
                popularity
                episodes
                season
                seasonYear
                hashtag
                isAdult
            }
        }
    }
```

I baisicly added the line with `seasonYear`. When I try to run this I get the error

```
{'data': None, 'errors': [{'message': 'Cannot query field "seasonYear" on type "Media".', 'status': 400, 'locations': [{'line': 22, 'column': 25}]}]}
```

but according to the documentation this is a valid key for the type `media`.

---

**TL;DR:** How can I search for something more complicated then a name, for example popularity, etc. How can I edit the code to be able to later search for something like the key `seasonYear`.

---

**EDIT:** After doing some more research and taking a look at some other examples online I was able to solve my first problem, which was to write a function that returns all the enteries with a certain `popularity`. The code with which I came up to do this is

```
        query ($query: Int) {
            Page {
                media(isAdult: false, popularity_greater: $query, type: ANIME) {
                    id
                    title {
                        english
                    }
                    episodes
                    startDate {
                        day
                        month
                        year
                    }
                    endDate {
                        day
                        month
                        year
                    }
                    genres
                    popularity
                }
            }
        }
```

So the only thing that remains is my second question about the `seasonYear` key.

Comment: I am reading this https://anilist.github.io/ApiV2-GraphQL-Docs/media.doc.html but I don't see the field `seasonYear` though.  I do see `season`

Comment: @Dora but when I look at the definition of `Page` [here](https://anilist.github.io/ApiV2-GraphQL-Docs/page.doc.html) there is a key for `seasonYear`... I'm a bit confused, could you maybe clear that up a bit.

Comment: Are you passing both `season` and `seasonYear` arguments? Per **"# seasonYear: The year of the season (Winter 2017 would also
# include December 2016 releases). Requires season argument"** _(line 16 of the Query docs)_

Comment: @ReidBallard I think I am (in my example above it is included), but I'm obviously not sure if I'm doing it correctly...

Comment: Ok, I see: I assumed that you were *searching* by seasonYear: you were just retrieving it correct? Looking at the docs again, under [Page here](https://anilist.github.io/ApiV2-GraphQL-Docs/page.doc.html) you'll see that `media` (note lowercase) links to these [docs here](https://anilist.github.io/ApiV2-GraphQL-Docs/media.doc.html): this `media` return is different from the `Media` (capitalized) query return object. This `media` node doesn't have `seasonYear` value, just like the error says. From the looks of it, you'll probably want either the `startDate` or `endDate` and parse year from there

Comment: @ReidBallard Thanks for the comment, that actually solved the problem I had!

Comment: Good to hear! I'll copy the solution down so that it's easier to find and the question can be marked as answered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Under [Page in the docs](https://anilist.github.io/ApiV2-GraphQL-Docs/page.doc.html), you'll see that `media` (note lowercase) links to these [docs here](https://anilist.github.io/ApiV2-GraphQL-Docs/media.doc.html): this `media` return is different from the `Media` (capitalized) query return object. This `media node` doesn't have the `seasonYear` value, just like the error says. From the looks of it, you'll probably want either the `startDate` or `endDate` and parse year from there